# Ensuring files are closed promptly

Tags: file, haskell, io, strict

I am writing a daemon that reads something from a small file, modifies it, and writes it back to the same file. I need to make sure that each file is closed promptly after reading before I try to write to it. I also need to make sure each file is closed promptly after writing, because I might occasionally read from it again right away.

I have looked into using binary-strict instead of binary, but it seems that only provides a strict Get, not a strict Put. Same issue with System.IO.Strict. And from reading the binary-strict documentation, I'm not sure it really solves my problem of ensuring that files are promptly closed. What's the best way to handle this? DeepSeq?

Here's a highly simplified example that will give you an idea of the structure of my application. This example terminates with

```
*** Exception: test.dat: openBinaryFile: resource busy (file is locked)
```

for obvious reasons.

```
import Data.Binary ( Binary, encode, decode )
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as B ( readFile, writeFile )
import Codec.Compression.GZip ( compress, decompress )

encodeAndCompressFile :: Binary a => FilePath -> a -> IO ()
encodeAndCompressFile f = B.writeFile f . compress . encode

decodeAndDecompressFile :: Binary a => FilePath -> IO a
decodeAndDecompressFile f = return . decode . decompress =<< B.readFile f

main = do
  let i = 0 :: Int
  encodeAndCompressFile "test.dat" i
  doStuff

doStuff = do
  i <- decodeAndDecompressFile "test.dat" :: IO Int
  print i
  encodeAndCompressFile "test.dat" (i+1)
  doStuff
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using a package such as [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), [iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee) or [enumerator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator). They provide much of the benefits of lazy IO (simpler code, potentially smaller memory footprint) without the lazy IO. Here's an example using [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) and [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal):

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile, sourceFile)
import Data.Conduit.Cereal (sinkGet, sourcePut)
import Data.Conduit.Zlib (gzip, ungzip)
import Data.Serialize (Serialize, get, put)

encodeAndCompressFile :: Serialize a => FilePath -> a -> IO ()
encodeAndCompressFile f v =
  runResourceT $ sourcePut (put v) $$ gzip =$ sinkFile f

decodeAndDecompressFile :: Serialize a => FilePath -> IO a
decodeAndDecompressFile f = do
  val <- runResourceT $ sourceFile f $$ ungzip =$ sinkGet get
  case val of
    Right v  -> return v
    Left err -> fail err

main = do
  let i = 0 :: Int
  encodeAndCompressFile "test.dat" i
  doStuff

doStuff = do
  i <- decodeAndDecompressFile "test.dat" :: IO Int
  print i
  encodeAndCompressFile "test.dat" (i+1)
  doStuff
```

Comment: Shameless plug: `pipes` is about to come out with prompt, deterministic and composable resource management within a week.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Excellent. Ping me when it's been released and I'll update this answer.

Comment: It's done.  I just announced it on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/txkb0/pipes_20_pipe_finalization/).

Answer (score 11):

All 'puts' or 'writes' to files are strict. The act of `writeFile` demands all Haskell data be evaluated in order to put it on disk.

So what you need to concentrate on is the lazy reading of the **input**. In your example above you both lazily read the file, then lazily decode it.

Instead, try reading the file strictly (e.g. with strict bytestrings), and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm confused.  I imagine that `i` is initially bound to a thunk in `doStuff`, and that no IO has actually taken place since we used the lazy `readFile`.  However, once we `print i`, doesn't that force the evaluation of `i`, and the completion of all the IO?  Did `decompress` not read all of the file, so it's left open?

Comment: Don, your explanation helped me understand why I don't need strict versions of 'puts' or 'writes'; thank you for that. However, I think I would also need to find a strict version of decompress. Ultimately I went with Nathan's solution because I find it a little easier to follow the code.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using conduits et al. would be to just use [`System.IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#g:21), which will allow you to control explicitly when files are closed with respect to the IO execution order.

You can use `openBinaryFile` followed by normal reading operations (probably the ones from [`Data.ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.2.1/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v:hGetContents)) and `hClose` when you're done with it, or `withBinaryFile`, which closes the file automatically (but beware [this sort of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406463/withfile-vs-openfile)).

Whatever the method you use, as Don said, you probably want to read as a strict bytestring and then convert the strict to lazy afterwards with [`fromChunks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.2.1/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:fromChunks).