# Pipes get Network.Socket.ByteString.recv: failed (Unknown error)

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Maybe a silly way to do things, but here it goes. I wanted to split the HTTP request send/receive from processing the response.

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.HTTP as HTTP
import Pipes.Core
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import Network.Socket (withSocketsDo)

fetch m url = do
  req <- lift $ HTTP.parseUrl url
  resp <- lift $ HTTP.withHTTP req m return
  url' <- respond $ HTTP.responseBody resp
  fetch m url'

client :: Client String (Producer PB.ByteString IO ()) IO ()
client = do
          b <- request "http://www.google.com"
          lift $ runEffect $ b >-> PB.stdout

main = withSocketsDo $ HTTP.withManager HTTP.tlsManagerSettings $ \m ->
     runEffect $ fetch m +>> client
```

Seems legitimate. But I get part of response printed and "Network.Socket.ByteString.recv: failed (Unknown error)". What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Sort of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406463/withfile-vs-openfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is this part:

```
HTTP.withHTTP req m return
```

There is a convention (not enforced by the types) that when a function begins with the word `with` that you are not allowed to let the resource it allocates escape from the block it encloses.  The reason why is that these `withXXX` functions dispose of the resource when the block completes, so the resource is invalid past that point.

So what happened is that you tried to `return` the response from the `withHTTP` block, but by the next line of code the response has already been disposed of.  The solution is to use `pipes-safe`, which allows you to acquire resources safely within a pipe using `Pipes.Safe.bracket`.  All you have to do is provide an open and close action:

```
fetch m url = do
    req  <- lift $ HTTP.parseUrl url
    url' <- bracket openSomething closeSomething $ \resp -> do
        respond $ HTTP.responseBody resp
    fetch m url'
```

That will ensure that `resp` is not released until after the `respond` completes.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a standard way to find out what to open/close? (In this case I did dig up that `withHTTP` is `withResponse` inside, and then `withResponse` explained that)

Comment: Usually they will be provided in the same module as the `with` function.  Also, check the `resourcet` package, which provides the `Resource` type.  That type lets you bundle the `open` and `close` action together so that you can recover them again later.