# Do Haskell files close automatically after readFile?

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

I want to use the Haskell function

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

to read the content of a file into a string. In [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/System-IO.html#v%3areadFile) I have read that "The file is read lazily, on demand, as with getContents."

I am not sure I understand this completely. For example, suppose that I write

```
s <- readFile "t.txt"
```

When this action is executed:

- The file is opened.
- The characters in s are actually read from the file as soon as (but not sooner) they are needed to evaluate some expression (e.g. if I evaluate `length s` **all** the content of the file will be read and the file will be closed).
- As soon as the last character has been read, the file handle associated to this call to `readFile` is closed (automatically).

Is my third statement correct? So, can I just invoke `readFile` without closing the file handle myself? Will the handle stay open as long as I have not consumed (visited) the whole result string?

**EDIT**

Here is some more information regarding my doubts. Suppose I have the following:

```
foo :: String -> IO String
foo filename = do
                  s <- readFile "t.txt"
                  putStrLn "File has been read."
                  return s
```

When the `putStrLn` is executed, I would (intuitively) expect that

1. `s` contains the whole content of file `t.txt`,
2. The handle used to read the file has been closed.

If this is not the case:

- What does `s` contain when `putStrLn` is executed?
- In what state is the file handle when `putStrLn` is executed?
- If when `putStrLn` is executed `s` does not contain the whole content of the file, when will this content actually be read, and when will the file be closed?

Comment: You can't close the handle yourself even if you wanted to. `hGetContents` puts the handle in semi-closed state, see [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v:hGetContents).

Comment: Does that mean the file is closed (from an OS standpoint) most of the time, and Haskell is just temporarily opening and reading into a memory buffer as characters are needed?  (reading the docs from question, looks like semi-closed = open for purposes of locking.)

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus Thanks for the link! If I understand correctly: the handle will be closed automatically when I reach the end of the file. But if I close the handle before the whole string has been evaluated, the result will be truncated.

Comment: What I also do not understand is what the type of `s` in my snippet is. If it is a string, how can it be read lazily? To read it lazily, shouldn't it have a type that contains `IO` in some way?

Comment: @Giorgio: In principle, you are correct, but lazy IO "cheats".

Comment: @Ben Millwood: That's quite surprising in a "pure" language like Haskell.

Comment: @Giorgio: It is, isn't it? Lazy IO is somewhat controversial for that reason. See also [What's so bad about Lazy I/O?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5892653/812053)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is my third statement correct?

Not quite, the file is not closed "As soon as the last character has been read", at least not usually, it lingers in the semi-closed state it was in during the read for a few moments, the IO-manager/runtime will close it when it next performs such actions. If you're rapidly opening and reading files, that lag may cause you to run out of file handles if the OS limit isn't too high.

For most use cases (in my limited experience), however, the closing of the file handle is timely enough. [There are people who disagree and view lazy IO as extremely dangerous in all cases. It definitely has pitfalls, but IMO its dangers are often overstated.]

> So, can I just invoke `readFile` without closing the file handle myself?

Yes, when you're using `readFile`, the file handle is closed automatically when the file contents has been entirely read or when it is noticed that the file handle is not referenced anymore.

> Will the handle stay open as long as I have not consumed (visited) the whole result string?

Not quite, `readFile` puts the file handle in a semi-closed state, described in the docs for `hGetContents`:

> Computation `hGetContents hdl` returns the list of characters corresponding to the unread portion of the channel or file managed by `hdl`, which is put into an intermediate state, semi-closed. In this state, `hdl` is effectively closed, but items are read from `hdl` on demand and accumulated in a special list returned by `hGetContents hdl.`

---

```
foo :: String -> IO String
foo filename = do
              s <- readFile "t.txt"
              putStrLn "File has been read."
              return s
```

<del>Ah, that's one of the pitfalls of lazy IO on the other end. Here the file is closed before its contents have been read. When `foo` returns, the file handle isn't referenced anymore, and then closed. The consumer of `foo`s result will then find that `s` is an empty string, because when `hGetContents` tries to actually read from the file, the handle is already closed.</del>

I confused the behaviour of `readFile` with that of

```
bracket (openFile file ReadMode) hClose hGetContents
```

there. `readFile` only closes the file handle after `s` is not referenced anymore, so it behaves correctly as expected here.

> When the `putStrLn` is executed, I would (intuitively) expect that
>
> 1. `s` contains the whole content of file `t.txt`,
> 2. The handle used to read the file has been closed.

No, `s` does not contain anything yet but a recipe to maybe get some characters from the file handle. The file handle is semi-closed, but not closed. It will be closed when the file contents has been entirely read, or `s` goes out of scope.

> If this is not the case:
>
> - What does `s` contain when `putStrLn` is executed?
> - In what state is the file handle when `putStrLn` is executed?
> - If when `putStrLn` is executed `s` does not contain the whole content of the file, when will this content actually be read, and when will the file be closed?

The first two questions have been answered, the answer to the third is "the file will be read when the contents is consumed", and it will be closed when the entire contents has been read or when it is no longer referenced.

That would be different with the above `bracket` invocation - `bracket` guarantees that the final operation, here the `hClose` will be run even if the other actions throw an exception, therefore its use is often recommended. However, the `hClose` is run when `bracket` returns, and then the `hGetContents` can't get any contents from the now really closed file handle. But `readFile` would not necessarily close the file handle if an exception occurs.

That is one of the dangers or quirks of lazy IO, files are not read until their contents is demanded, and if you use lazy IO wrongly, that will be too late and you don't get any contents.

It's a trap many (or even most) fall into one time or another, but after having been bitten by it, one quickly learns when IO needs to be non-lazy and do it non-lazily in those cases.

The alternatives (iteratees, enumerators, conduits, pipes, ...) avoid those traps [unless the implementer made a mistake], but are considerably less nice to use in those cases where lazy IO is perfectly fine. On the other hand, they treat the cases where laziness is not desired much better.

Comment: "the list of characters corresponding to the unread portion of the channel or file managed by hdl": Does this mean that the returned list is read into main memory at once and then the file handle is put into semi-closed state?

Comment: No. That's the point of the lazy reading, it will only read what you consume (well, not exactly, it reads in chunks, asks for `bufferSize` bytes at a time, and the size of the buffer is by default 4 or 8K iirc), and if you don't keep references to the already consumed parts, they can be garbage collected, so that you can read a file and count the commas in it [silly example] in constant memory.

Comment: "Not quite, readFile puts the file handle in a semi-closed state": Ok, but from the point of view of the operating system, the handle should stay open until all characters have been read, or is the file reopened if one consumes more characters at a later point in time?

Comment: "Consumers will get an empty string for the file contents.": Very surprising! If `s` contains all the information to read the content lazily, how do I know when it is too late to reduce `s`?

Comment: "When foo returns, the file handle isn't referenced anymore, and then closed.": I would expect that the handle isn't referenced anymore right after `readFile` has been executed, and that at that point the file is closed and its content flushed into the list `s` (isn't `s` just a list here? I do not see the `IO` in its type). I do not see what is so special about exiting the function `foo` that causes the file handle to be closed (or scheduled for being closed as soon as possible).

Comment: Oh, dang, I got confused myself, `readFile` is behaving properly, it's only `bracket (openFile file ReadMode) hClose hGetContents` that doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

> When the putStrLn is executed, I would (intuitively) expect that `s` contains the whole content of file t.txt,

You need to think about the fact you're using lazy IO here. Reading from the file merely creates an unevalauted string computation that, if it is later required, will then read the file.

By using lazy IO you defer your IO until the value is needed.

Once the last character of your file has been read, or all references to the open file are dropped (e.g. your `s` value), your open file will be closed by the garbage collector.

Comment: To clarify, it's not reading the last character that triggers the close, it's trying to read beyond the last character that detects the EOF condition and closes the file.