# Haskell's hGetContents isn't returning anything, even though I know the file contains text

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have a small bit of code that isn't behaving as I expected it too:

```
tempTest = do
    (_,tHand) <- openTempFile "." "tempTest.txt"
    hPutStr tHand "Test!"
    read <- hGetContents tHand
    putStrLn read
```

It writes to the file correctly, but when asked to display the contents to the screen, it shows only a new line (without any quotes).
Given how simple this is, I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding how getContents works. From what I understand, it reads the file in chunks instead of all at once; which prevents the memory from being filled up by a massive file being read. Why is "read' not receiving  anything from hGetContents?
Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that similar problems often turn up with Haskell's standard IO routines because of _lazyness_. That was completely innocent in this case, but generally it's often a good idea to just go for completely strict IO, i.e. open & read an entire file and immediately close it: the time and memory needed is often neglectable (though sometimes it isn't of course!), and you get much simpler, reliable semantics.

Comment: I haven't knowingly used anything strict in Haskell yet. The only method I know of for ensuring strictness is the $! operator, which, as far as I know causes `seq` to be called during the application (so I guess I know of `seq` aswell). I have yet to use either though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that the handle of your file points to the end of the file. This should work:

```
tempTest = do
    (_,tHand) <- openTempFile "." "tempTest.txt"
    hPutStr tHand "Test!"
    hSeek tHand AbsoluteSeek 0 -- move the file handle to beginning of file
    read <- hGetContents tHand
    putStrLn read
```

Demo:

```
λ> tempTest
Test!
```

Here using the `hSeek` function, you move the `Handle` to the beginning of the file. Also, I would suggest you to close the file handle using `hClose` function after your work is done.

Comment: Wow. Now that I think about it, it makes sense that the handle would be at the end of the file, just having written something -_-. Thank you. Quickest answer ever.

Comment: @Sibi I'm a little wary of suggesting that one combine `hClose` with lazy IO like `hGetContents`, it can so easily do the wrong thing.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen What can go wrong? Does it have a chance of cutting the text early?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892653/whats-so-bad-about-lazy-i-o) to get the ideas of when lazy IO will be a problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, that's it.