# How to improve the performance of Haskell IO?

Tags: haskell, io

It seems that Haskell's IO is relatively slow.

For example, comparing Haskell with Python

```
#io.py
import sys
s=sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.write(s)
```

,

```
-- io.hs
main = do
    s <- getContents
    putStr s
```

Their performance (gen.py writes 512k data into stdout):

The Python version:

```
$ time python gen.py | python io.py > /dev/null

real    0m0.203s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The Haskell version:

```
$ time python gen.py | runhaskell io.hs > /dev/null

real    0m0.562s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

It seems that the Haskell one is far lower. Is there any problem with my test? Or is it just the inherent problem of Haskell?

Thanks.

Comment: Both times include the time it takes to compile the program Try timing `gen.pyc` (pre-compiled) vs a precompiled binary from `io.hs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is slow because it uses lazy IO with `String`-s. Both have their own overheads.

In particular, `String` is a linked list of `Char`-s, therefore it has two words of space overhead for each character (one word for the constructor tag and one for the forward pointer), and each character takes up at least one word (one word for cached low characters, three words for uncached characters).

Strict IO with byte or unicode array input is much faster. Try to benchmark the following:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = B.putStr =<< B.getContents
```

Or the following:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main = T.putStr =<< T.getContents
```

Comment: Both versions cost about 520ms (about 10% of improvement). And I think that lazy IO is deprecated because of its way of releasing resources? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892653/whats-so-bad-about-lazy-i-o

Comment: Try compiling with -O2.

Comment: `runhaskell` is always slow, no matter what the job is. GHC optimizes for executables, not interpreter speed.