# How do I read (and parse) a file and then append to the same file without getting an exception?

Tags: file, haskell, exception, locked

I am trying to read from a file correctly in Haskell but I seem to get this error.

*** Exception: neo.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)
This is my code.

```
import Data.Char
import Prelude
import Data.List
import Text.Printf
import Data.Tuple
import Data.Ord
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative((<*))

import Text.Parsec
    ( Parsec, ParseError, parse        -- Types and parser
    , between, noneOf, sepBy, many1    -- Combinators
    , char, spaces, digit, newline     -- Simple parsers
    )
```

These are the movie fields.

```
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type UserRatings = (String,Int) 
type Film = (Title, Director, Year , [UserRatings])
type Period = (Year, Year)
type Database = [Film]
```

This is the Parsing of all the types in order to read correctly from the file

```
-- Parse a string to a string
stringLit :: Parsec String u String
stringLit = between (char '"') (char '"') $ many1 $ noneOf "\"\n"

-- Parse a string to a list of strings
listOfStrings :: Parsec String u [String]
listOfStrings = stringLit `sepBy` (char ',' >> spaces)

-- Parse a string to an int
intLit :: Parsec String u Int
intLit = fmap read $ many1 digit
-- Or `read <$> many1 digit` with Control.Applicative
stringIntTuple :: Parsec  String u (String  , Int)
stringIntTuple = liftM2 (,) stringLit intLit

film :: Parsec String u Film
film = do
    -- alternatively `title <- stringLit <* newline` with Control.Applicative
    title <- stringLit
    newline
    director <- stringLit
    newline
    year <- intLit
    newline
    userRatings <- stringIntTuple
    newline
    return (title, director, year, [userRatings])

films :: Parsec String u [Film]
films = film `sepBy` newline
```

This is the main program (write "main" in winghci to start the program)

```
-- The Main
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "Enter your Username:  "
    name <- getLine
    filmsDatabase <- loadFile "neo.txt"
    appendFile "neo.txt" (show filmsDatabase)
    putStrLn "Your changes to the database have been successfully saved."
```

This is the loadFile function

```
loadFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError [Film])
loadFile filename = do
database <- readFile filename 
return $ parse films "Films" database
```

the other txt file name is neo and includes some movies like this

```
"Blade Runner"
"Ridley Scott"
1982
("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)

"The Fly"
"David Cronenberg"
1986
("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",6)
```

Just copy paste everything include a txt file in the same directory and test it to see the error i described.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whoopsy daisy, being lazy
tends [to make file changes crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892653/whats-so-bad-about-lazy-i-o).
File's [not closed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents), [as supposed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:8)
thus [the error](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#v:isAlreadyInUseError) gets imposed.
This small guile, by `loadFile`
is what you must reconcile.
But don't fret, least not yet,
I will show you, let's get set.

---

As many other functions that work with `IO` in `System.IO`, `readFile` doesn't actually consume any input. It's lazy. Therefore, the file [doesn't get closed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:readFile), unless all its content has been consumed (it's then half-closed):

> The file is read lazily, on demand, as with [`getContents`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:getContents).

We can demonstrate this on a shorter example:

```
main = do
  let filename = "/tmp/example"
  writeFile filename "Hello "
  contents <- readFile filename
  appendFile filename "world!"   -- error here
```

This will fail, since we never actually checked `contents` (entirely). If you get all the content (for example with printing, `length` or similar), it won't fail anymore:

```
main = do
  let filename = "/tmp/example2"
  writeFile filename "Hello "
  content <- readFile filename
  putStrLn content
  appendFile filename "world!"   -- no error
```

Therefore, we need either something that **really** closes the file, or we need to make sure that we've read all the contents before we try to append to the file.

For example, you can use [`withFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile) together with some "magic" function `force` that makes sure that the content really gets evaluated:

```
readFile' filename = withFile filename ReadMode $ \handle -> do
  theContent <- hGetContents handle
  force theContent
```

However, `force` is tricky to achieve. You could use [bang patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html), but this will evaluate the list only to WHNF (basically just the first character). You could use the functions by [`deepseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq), but that adds another dependency and is probably not allowed in your assignment/exercise.

Or you could use any function that will somehow make sure that all elements are evaluated or sequenced. In this case, we can use a small trick and `mapM return`:

```
readFile' filename = withFile filename ReadMode $ \handle -> do
  theContent <- hGetContents handle
  mapM return theContent
```

It's good enough, but you would use something like `pipes` or `conduit` instead in production.

The other method is to make sure that we've really used all the contents. This can be done by using another parsec parser method instead, namely `runParserT`. We can combine this with our `withFile` approach from above:

```
parseFile :: ParsecT String () IO a -> FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError a) 
parseFile p filename = withFile filename ReadMode $ \handle ->
  hGetContents handle >>= runParserT p () filename
```

Again, `withFile` makes sure that we close the file. We can use this now in your `loadFilm`:

```
loadFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError [Film])
loadFile filename = parseFile films filename
```

This version of `loadFile` won't keep the file locked anymore.

Comment: fn and runParserT are not in scope though :/

Comment: @Max: While `fn` was a typo, `runParserT` is exported by `Text.Parsec`. You have to add it to the import list.

Comment: i made it work using the answer Sibi said but still the films are not been read do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @Max: Sure. Your parser and your file format don't match. But that's a question for another post, since you never actually showed the content of "neo.txt".

Comment: i did the other txt above 
please look as your answer is more correct and i want to do yours but it has 25 films instead.

Comment: @Max: Whoops, sorry. I didn't see the contents. The thing is, all answers here concern the error (`*** Exception: neo.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)`). While your parser is part of your question, the __parser error__ (not the exception) wasn't the original topic. Changing the topic of a question is discouraged. Instead, open a new one. To get more feedback sooner, try to make the code a little bit shorter in the new question, e.g. just post your parser and the original string, not the functions that concern file handling.

Comment: but still i cannot move to a new post because this answer gives this error
‘Parsec’ is applied to too many type arguments
    In the type signature for ‘parseFile’:
      parseFile :: Parsec String () IO a
                   -> FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError a)
if you help me get over that i will make a new question so you can come and i will also tick your answer :) so please help me.

Comment: The `T` in `ParsecT` isn't a typo. `Parsec s u a` is actually `ParsecT s u Identity a`, and in this case I want to use `IO` instead of `Identity`, therefore `ParsecT`, not `Parsec`.

Comment: when i do that i get like 2 very big errors 
`Couldn't match expected type ‘IO (Either ParseError a)’
                with actual type ‘IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r0) -> IO r0’
    Relevant bindings include`


`Couldn't match expected type ‘Handle -> IO (Either ParseError a)’
                with actual type ‘[Char]’`

I am really sorry that I am so pain for you but i don't have the experience :/

Comment: That's because I missed the `ReadMode` as second parameter in `withFile`. Sorry.

Comment: can you copy the parseFile here again please? :/

Comment: @Max: I did, see [the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35844504/revisions).

Comment: thank you Zeta i will open a new topic for the parse problem what should i post the parser and the neo.txt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105578/discussion-between-max-and-zeta).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `readFile` doesn't actually read the entire file into memory immediately; it opens the file and instantly returns a string. As you "look at" the string, behind the scenes the file is being read. So when `readFile` returns, the file it still open for reading, and you can't do anything else with it. This is called "lazy I/O", and many people consider it to be "evil" precisely because it tends to cause problems like the one you currently have.

There are several ways you can go about fixing this. Probably the simplest is to just force the whole string into memory before continuing. Calculating the `length` of the string will do that — but only if you "use" the length for something, because the length itself is lazy. (See how this rapidly becomes messy? This is why people avoid lazy I/O.)

The simplest thing you could try is printing the number of films loaded right before you try to append to the database.

```
main = do
  putStr "Enter your Username:  "
  name <- getLine
  filmsDatabase <- loadFile "neo.txt"
  putStrLn $ "Loaded " ++ show (length filmsDatabase) ++ " films."
  appendFile "neo.txt" (show filmsDatabase)
  putStrLn "Your changes to the database have been successfully saved."
```

It's kind of evil that what looks like a simple print message is actually fundamental to making the code work though!

The other alternative is to save the new database under a different name, and then delete the old file and rename the new one over the top of the old one. This does have the advantage that if the program were to crash half way through saving, you haven't just lost all your stuff.

Comment: i tried to do that but still it tries to load and this happens again.
Loaded 0 films.
*Main> *** Exception: neo.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)

Comment: Small remark: if `parse` in `loadFile` does not consume the whole input, the handle will still be open.

Comment: @Zeta Hmm, yes... that's possibly the problem.