# Haskell: hSetFileSize: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

Tags: file, haskell, io

Can some body help me what is wrong with my program. When i tried to run following program, I am getting the following error message:

> `hSetFileSize`: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

```
import System.IO

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter file name (Including full path) to read"
    fileName <- getLine

    handle <- openFile fileName ReadMode
    sizeBeforeTrunc <- hFileSize handle
    content <- readFile fileName 

    putStrLn $ "Size of the file Before truncation is " ++ (show sizeBeforeTrunc) ++ " bytes" 
    putStrLn $ "Content of the file is " ++ content

    putStrLn "**************************************"
    let n = sizeBeforeTrunc `div` 2
    putStrLn $ "Truncating file to " ++ (show n) ++ " bytes"

    info1 <- hSetFileSize handle (toInteger 10)
    putStrLn $ show info1
    sizeAfterTrunc <- hFileSize handle

    putStrLn $ "Size of the file After truncation is " ++ (show sizeAfterTrunc) ++ " bytes" 
    putStrLn $ "Content of the file is " ++ content        

    hClose handle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file for reading only; but truncating is a write operation.

What you can do instead is something like

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter file name (Including full path) to read"
    fileName <- getLine

    sizeBeforeTrunc <- withFile fileName ReadMode $ \h -> do
        sizeBeforeTrunc <- hFileSize h
        content <- hGetContents h

        putStrLn $ "Size of the file Before truncation is " ++ (show sizeBeforeTrunc) ++ " bytes" 
        putStrLn $ "Content of the file is " ++ content

    putStrLn "**************************************"
    let n = sizeBeforeTrunc `div` 2
    putStrLn $ "Truncating file to " ++ (show n) ++ " bytes"

    sizeAfterTrunc <- withFile fileName WriteMode $ \h -> do       
        info1 <- hSetFileSize h (toInteger 10)
        putStrLn $ show info1
        hFileSize h

    putStrLn $ "Size of the file After truncation is " ++ (show sizeAfterTrunc) ++ " bytes" 
    putStrLn $ "Content of the file is " ++ content
```

Comment: Additional remark: using `openFile fileName WriteMode` will lead to an error in `content <- readFile fileName`, since GHC's runtime only allows either multiple readers or a single writer. Opening the file twice (once for getting the size and reading the content; then for truncating) seems more reasonable.

Comment: @Zeta: good point, I've updated the answer to show a possible solution that first does the `ReadMode` operations, then the `WriteMode` ones.

Comment: Also, I'd much rather use some bespoke strict IO functions (like [these](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict/docs/System-IO-Strict.html)) to read the file before truncating; the standard IO functions are, unfortunately, lazy.

Comment: Instead of opening the file twice, you could open with `ReadWriteMode` (I think). +1 for using `withFile` instead of a `open`/`close` combo.

Comment: @user2407038: I'm happy to change it to use `ReadWriteMode` but only if at least one of us actually tries it out :)

Comment: @user2407038 Err, `hGetContents` will put the handle in a semi-closed state. After all, there's a reason for [my last poem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35844504/1139697). \*sigh\* Although one had to change it for this: *Whoopsy daisy, being lazy / tends to make file changes crazy. / Handle is gone / and all along / you ask yourself "what went wrong"? / Don't yet cry / keep on, try! / All the suffering soon pass by*.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note: This answer is written in literate Haskell. Save it with `.lhs` as extension and try it in GHCi or compile it.</sup>

```
> import System.IO
```

Changing a file isn't a read-only operation. You need to open the file for writing. However, this will lead to problems, since you may only have either a single writer or multiple readers. Since you use `readFile` your opening the file for reading, so you cannot simply change the open mode.

It gets easier if we refactor your code. We can immediately see two violations of don't-repeat-yourself, namely getting the size and telling the content. So let's fix that:

```
> putAndCount :: FileName -> String -> IO Int
> putAndCount fn msg = withFile fn ReadMode $ \handle -> do
>     size    <- hFileSize handle
>     content <- hGetContents handle
>     putStrLn $ "Size of the file " ++ msg ++ " is " ++ show size ++ " bytes"
>     putStrLn $ "Content of the file is " ++ content
>     return size
```

`withFile` makes sure that our handle is closed and cannot screw with further actions. Now let's write another function to change the size of a file without using a handle:

```
> setFileSize :: FileName -> Integer -> IO ()
> setFileSize fn s = withFile fn ReadWriteMode $ \handle -> 
>     hSetFileSize handle s
```

It's important to use `ReadWriteMode` and **not** `WriteMode` here, since `WriteMode` will truncate the file to zero bytes! That's the same behavior as in C's `fopen`, by the way.

Now we have all tools necessary to complete the task:

```
> main :: IO ()
> main = do
>     putStrLn "Enter file name (Including full path) to read"
>     fileName <- getLine
>
>     sizeBeforeTrunc <- putAndCount fileName "Before truncation"    
>     putStrLn "**************************************"
> 
>     let n = sizeBeforeTrunc `div` 2
>     putStrLn $ "Truncating file to " ++ (show n) ++ " bytes"    
>     setFileSize fileName n
>     putAndCount fileName "After truncation"
```