# Fastest way to read large binary file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to process a binary file that is too large to read into memory. Currently I use [ByteString.Lazy.readFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html) to stream the bytes. I thought it would be a good idea to use the [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0) package to make my program faster. However, the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html) for `readFile` says:

> `readFile :: FilePath -> (Stream (Of String) IO () -> IO a) -> IO a`
>
> Read the lines of a file, using a function of the type: 'Stream (Of String) IO () -> IO a' to turn the stream into a value of type 'IO a'.

So the `streaming` package only reads ASCII text files? Can I use this package to read a binary file as bytes?

Comment: You are probably looking for [*streaming-bytestring*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring) and [*streaming-binary*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-binary). See also: [reverse dependencies of *streaming*](https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/streaming).

Comment: There's also pipes-bytestring http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-bytestring and conduit http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.1.1/docs/Conduit.html#v:sourceFile

Comment: Why'd you think `streaming` would make your program faster? Packages like that are mostly meant to make dealing with data streams _more convenient_, not to make them _faster_.

Comment: @Cubic In my case, speed is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on @Cubic's comment, while there's a general consensus that lazy I/O should be avoided in production code and replaced with a streaming approach, this is **not** directly related to performance.  If you're writing a program to do some one-off processing of a large file, as long as you have a lazy I/O version running fine now, there's  probably no good *performance* reason to convert it over to a streaming package.

In fact, streaming is more likely to add some overhead, so I suspect that a well optimized lazy I/O solution would out-perform a well optimized streaming solution, in most cases.

The main reasons for avoiding Lazy I/O have been [previously discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892653/whats-so-bad-about-lazy-i-o).  In a nutshell, lazy I/O makes it difficult to consistently manage resources (e.g., file handles and network sockets), makes it hard to reason about space usage (e.g., a small program change can cause your memory usage to explode), and is occasionally "unsafe" if the timing and ordering of the I/O in question matters (usually not a problem if you're just reading in one set of files and/or writing out another set of files).

Short-running utility programs for reading and/or writing large files are probably good candidates to be written in a lazy I/O style.  As long as they don't have any obvious space leaks when they're run, they're probably fine.

Answer (score 3):

With only *streaming* and *bytestring*, one can write something like:

```
import           Data.ByteString
import           Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import           System.IO

fromHandle :: Int -> Handle -> Stream (Of ByteString) IO ()
fromHandle chunkSize h = 
    S.untilRight $ do bytes <- Data.ByteString.hGet h chunkSize
                      pure $ if Data.ByteString.null bytes then Right ()
                                                           else Left bytes
```

Using [`hGet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:hGet), [`null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:null) from *bytestring*, and [`untilRight`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:untilRight) from *streaming*. You will need to use [`withFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile) to get the `Handle`, and consume the `Stream` within the callback:

```
dump :: FilePath -> IO ()
dump file = withFile file ReadMode go
 where
   go :: Handle -> IO ()
   go = S.mapM_ (Data.ByteString.hPut stdout) . fromHandle 4096
```